# Javascript function breaking a whole program?

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop

I've written a program that basically pops alert boxes whenever buttons are pressed. The problem is, one of my functions is behaving pretty weirdly and I can't figure out why. Sometimes the function just doesn't work, other times it completely stops the program from sending alerts that other functions are in charge of. Is there something wrong with the syntax I'm trying to use? I've tried a lot of variations...

This simple thing works:

```
function popup(){
      alert(5+6);
};
```

This does not:

```
function popup(){
            c = 0;
                if(c=0){
                    alert(5+6);
                }
};
```

This prevents the whole program from working:

```
    function popup(){
        x=0
        y=0
        while(x=0;x<array.length;x++)
            if(y>0){
                alert(5+6);
            }
            else(y=0){
                alert(1+2)
                y++
            }
    };
```

Comment: else(y=0)

do you mean:

      else(y==0)  - You are doing an assigment

Comment: That's not how "while" loops work. I think you're going for a "for" loop there.

Comment: I think this is a syntax error, and that will indeed stop the whole program from working. You should have gotten an error in the console about it.

Comment: Where is your array? Initialized earlier or?

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean

```
else if (y==0){
```

and not

```
else(y=0){
```

`y=0` sets y to 0 and always returns 0, whatever the value of y was before.

`while` takes one statement as condition (see [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)). Your while loop was probably checking the result of x++ so it could never end.

You should probably have a for loop.

Setting y to 0 just before entering the loop where the value is tested is very strange. I guess y should be `array[x]`.

```
function popup(){
    for (x=0; x<array.length; x++) {
        var y = array[x]; // just a guess, but this seems reasonnable
        if (y>0){
            alert(5+6);
        } else if (y==0) {
            alert(1+2);
            y++;
        }
};
```

But adding all the `;` and formating/indenting properly your code would probably avoid you a lot of headaches.

I recommend to stick to [Google's javascript style guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml).

Comment: Ah thank you I'll try that out, for some reason the code isn't indenting properly on the website so it looks a little odd.

Comment: @dystroy You didn't really explain that == is the comparison operator, and that = is for assignment.

Comment: @IanAtkin I try to explain it but as the `if` was missing too and the loop was a while instead of a loop, it's a little hard to decipher in what ways the code was bugging.

Comment: Oh thanks! completely forgot that == is a comparison and = is assignment, thanks alot:)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to do a for loop here.

if (y=0) makes an assigment, not a comparison.

else(y=0){ should be "else if". "else if" takes a comparison, where as - else becomes true if the "if" clause before it was false.

**It seems like your array is not initialized? - or is this initialized earlier?**

I think this is closer to what you want?:

```
function popup() {
    y = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        if (y > 0) {
            alert(5 + 6);
        }
        else if (y == 0)
        {
            alert(1 + 2);
            y++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you that worked:) I don't quite know why my function disabled the other popups (aside from perhaps my bad assignment operators), but this works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you please accept the answer?

Also, as Thilo commented. Check your browsers console, it usually tells you the line where the error is :)